# Javascript only access object property after page reload

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, geoxml3

I'm have a pretty weird problem with my code. I'm using geoxml3 to parse a kml file, and it parses all the polylines ok, but when it gets to the markers, the console says it's `undefined`. The weird part is that every time I reload the page, it works fine, but every time I open in a new tab, it breaks again. Even weirder, when I put a `console.log` right before the condition to check if it's a polyline or a marker, the browser's console shows there to be a `marker` property.

Here's my useTheData function that geoxml3 requires:

```
function useTheData(doc){
console.log("Starts Parse");
console.log(doc[0].placemarks.length);  
for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++){
    console.log("i: "+i+", placemark:");    
    console.log(doc[0].placemarks[i]); //here the .marker property exists in the console
    console.log(".marker:");
    console.log(doc[0].placemarks[i].marker); //here it says it's undefined!
    if(doc[0].placemarks[i].polyline){ //check if it's a polyline
        google.maps.event.addListener(doc[0].placemarks[i].polyline, 'click', select_option);
    }
    else{
        console.log("### i = "+i);
        console.log("1");
        console.log(doc[0].placemarks[i].marker); //here, the exact same object, doesn't have the marker property!
        console.log("2");
        google.maps.event.addListener(doc[0].placemarks[i].marker, 'click', select_option); //Because of that, the first time the page loads, it get's stuck in the function cuz it can't access the .marker
        console.log("3");
        doc[0].placemarks[i].marker.setIcon({
            url: "img/bola.png",
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 5)
        });
        console.log("4");
    }
}
console.log("End Parse");
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', select_option);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (and some indication of what version of geoxml3 you are using).

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: select_option is not defined`

Comment: I'm using the very last version from april 6 downloaded from github.
The problem is that the geoxml gets a kml from a local server, I'll try to publish the code on a server to be able to fully reproduce the error.
But all the addListener functions can be removed and the error still happens.

Comment: Which branch? polys or kmz?  I don't see the reported error with the polys branch (at least in Chrome).  You can provide a snippet of KML in your question that will generate the error (I'm guessing you have both polylines and markers) and the minimal/complete javascript/HTML

Comment: From the kmz branch. I tried the one from the polys branch and it also worked fine! I just had to do a little more coding because the poly branch doesn't support the extendeddata nodes from the KML. It's working fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to one of the differences between the polys and kmz branches of geoxml3.

The kmz branch of geoxml3 has an img onload event handler for icons that can cause them not to be available until sometime after the parse operation is finished.  It makes the icon sizing work better, but can cause issues like you see in the `afterParse` function.